# Progress bar is not resetting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a progress bar. It's a timer but somehow when I click on the button/box result to start over, the progress bar will show up but won't reset.

It won't start at 100 and get to 0 by itself like it does the first time. Any ideas why? I've already checked that I reset all variables!

```
 $("document").ready(function(){
  var number = 0;
  $("#cat").on("click", function(){
    var y = Math.random()*900;
    var d = Math.random()*300;
    var w = Math.random()*300;
    if (w < 100) {
    $("#cat").css({left: y, top: d, width: "60px", height: "70px"});
    }
    if (w > 100) {
      $("#cat").css({left: y, top: d, width: "170px", height: "190px"});
    }
    number++;
  });

  var i = 100;
  var counterBack = setInterval(function(){
   i --;
   if(i > 0){
    document.getElementById("timer").style.width = i+"%";
   }
   if (i < 25) {
    $("#question").fadeOut(300, "swing");
   }
   if (i === 0) {
    clearTimeout(counterBack);
    $("#cat").fadeOut(700);
    $("#progressbar").fadeOut(700);

    if (number < 25){
      $("body").append("<button id='box'><h3 id='sorry'>Oops! Sorry! Cats caught: <span id='yep'>"+number+"</span></h3></button>");
      $("#box").delay(700).fadeIn(100);
      $("#box").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        var number = 0;
        $("#cat").css({"height": "300px", "width": "290px", "margin-top": "80px", "margin-left":"300px", "position":"absolute", "float": "center"});
        $("#cat").fadeIn();
        $("#progressbar").fadeIn();
        var i = 100;
        setInterval(counterBack);
      }); 
    }
    else if (number >= 25){
      $("body").append("<div id='box'><h3 id='hurray'>Yay! You did it! Cats caught: <span id='yep'>"+number+"</span></h3></div>");
      $("#box").delay(700).fadeIn(100);
    }
  } 
 }, 200);

});
```

HTML

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bowlby+One+SC" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bowlby+One" />

<body>

  <div id="content">
    <img id="cat" src="http://backgroundidea.info/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/black-and-white-cat-background-tumblr-black-cat-stock-i-by-anothersunrise-on-deviantart-beautiful.png"/>
    <h3></h3>
  </div>

  <div class="progress" id="progressbar">
  <div id="timer" class="progress-bar progress-danger active" role="progressbar"aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"><h1 id="question">Can you catch 25 cats?</h1>  </div>  

  </div> 
</body>
```

Comment: Did you notice that your `<div id="timer"` doesn't close correctly? `<div id="timer"... aria-valuemax="100"</div> `

Comment: Hadn't noticed! Thank you! gonna update my HTML now as the bar problem is still happening!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several problems:

1. In your `.box` button click you need to set the global variable `i = 100` and not `var i = 0;` because this last will create a local variable, the same for `number`.
2. In order to reset your timer (`setInerval`) you need to give a name to your timer function.
3. You need to add/append `.box` div outside the timer function and use `.html()` to change the content. Because on every interval resets you need to check if the `.box` exists!
4. Attach the click handler outside the timer function because on each interval resets you will reattach the click handler, therefore, getting a weird behaviour.

Your code reformed https://jsfiddle.net/iRbouh/yfpmxcuk/.